# Double Integral bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am attempting a question that asks me to evaluate
$$
\iint_D (x^2+y^2) dx dy 
$$
where $D$ is the finite region in the positive quadrant bounded by the curves 
$$
x^2 - y^2 = \pm 1, \quad xy = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

So, I thought of using the transformation $x^2 - y^2 = u$ and $xy=v$, and computed the Jacobian and all that and get to the integral

$$
\iint_D \frac{1}{v} du dv.
$$

But I can't get the bounds to work. I thought $u$ would be between $-1$ and $1$, and $v$ would be between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. However then the integral is not finite. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Jacobian is not right.  I get
$$
    \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}
    = \begin{vmatrix} 2x & y \\ -2y & x \end{vmatrix}
    = 2(x^2 + y^2)
$$
In terms of the area elements,
$$
    du\,dv = 2(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy
$$
So if $R$ is the rectangle $[-1,1] \times [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ in the $uv$-plane, then
$$
    \iint_D (x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\iint_R \,du \,dv = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \operatorname{Area}(R) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Yes I had gone through defining $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u,v$, and must have gotten lost in the transformation. Thank you !